# Assigning property to JS object using another objects property value as the property name

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I want to use the value of an objects property to name the property of another object.  Easy to do in PHP:

```
$object1->property = 'name';
$object2->{$object1->property} = "value";
echo $object2->name; //outputs "value"
```

But in Javascript I can't figure out how to do this.  The curly braces are used a different way.

Anyone know the php equivalent in javascript?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
object2[object1.property] = "value";
```