# Get property of object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

Basically I have a form with a `<select>` that chooses which set of data to use (values are "m", "f" and "c"). I then have a dictionary/object with the data in:

```
var gdas = {
    // Male
    "m": {
        "calories": 2500,
        "protein": 55,
        "carbohydrates": 300,
        "sugars": 120,
        "fat": 95,
        "saturates": 30,
        "fibre": 24,
        "salt": 6
    },

    // Female
    "f": {
        "calories": 2000,
        // etc.
};
```

Now I need to get `gdas.m`/`gdas.f`/`gdas.c` but I'm not sure what syntax to use - I've tried:

```
var mode = $("#mode").val();
var gda_set = gdas.mode;
var gda_set = gdas[mode];
```

What's the right syntax/method for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigning property to JS object using another objects property value as the property name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792936/assigning-property-to-js-object-using-another-objects-property-value-as-the-prope)

Comment: `gdas[mode]` should work

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since you're referencing the property via a variable, you need the bracket notation.

```
var gda_set = gdas[mode];
```

...which is the same notation you would use if you were passing a String.

```
var gda_set = gdas["f"];
```

Comment: You're right, I'm a bit confused as to why it didn't work the first time, probably had my break point in the wrong place. Thanks!

Comment: @Ross - You're welcome. :o) A fairly common mistake is to place a `.` before the opening bracket, as in `gdas.[mode]`. Anyway, glad you got it working!

Answer (score 2):

You don't have "mode" attribute in that variable. You must use if's to detect which sex you are processing and get `gdas.m.fibre` or `gdas.f.salt`.

Comment: That's not really his question, is it? He needs to find out how he can make the `.m.` and `.f.` dynamic depending on the selected value

Answer (score 0):

You can use gdas[mode], it selects the element that is indexed by the value of mode.