# How to access javascript object methods with a variable?

Tags: javascript, object, methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get property of object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695243/get-property-of-object-in-javascript)

```
var Terminal = function() {
  this.walk = function() {
    alert('hello');
  }
  this.go = 'walk';
  this.move = 'walk';
}

var term = new Terminal();
var fn = 'walk';
if (term.hasOwnProperty(fn)) {
  term.{fn};
}
```

How can I run the method term.walk() using the string 'walk'?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695243/get-property-of-object-in-javascript This has been asked many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways.  The simplest is

```
term[fn]();
```

Or alternatively

```
var funcObj = term[fn];
funcObj.apply(term);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `term[fn]` to access the `<fn>` property of `term`.

All properties can be accessed using `object["propertyname"]`. Globally defined properties/methods can be called through `window["propertyname"]`.

There's only one occasion where variables cannot be accessed through `obj["prop_name"]`:

```
function foo(){
    var bar = 759;
     //There is no "obj" where obj.bar exists.
}
```