# get javascript value using a variable

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get property of object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695243/get-property-of-object-in-javascript)

If I have the following:

```
var test ='bar';

var sections = {
    foo: 'value1',
    bar: 'value2',
    baz: 'value3'
};
```

I can use sections.foo to output 'value1'. Thats fine. However what if I want to get the value from sections according to another variable. Although this doesnt work what I mean is something like:

```
sections.test
```

Where test is the variable declared earlier, so the value returned would be 'bar'.

I dont work a awful lot with js so any help would be appreciated :) .. or if im approaching this the wrong way, feel free to say.

thanks

-->EDIT

The reason I wanted to do this is because the variable 'test' will be coming from the url and then I just wanted to load up further information depending on what page the user was on. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `[]` instead of `.`.

```
sections[test] // value2
```

Comment: +1 for beating me while I was fiddling - http://jsfiddle.net/YgcDf/

Comment: Perfect. Cant believe it was so simple lol. Didnt realise it can just be accessed like an array. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Where test is the variable declared earlier, so the value returned
>   would be 'bar'.

```
if (sections.hasOwnProperty(test)) return test;
```

But what you probably meant was

```
if (sections.hasOwnProperty(test)) return sections[test];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access it as an array index, like so: `sections[test]`.  But, AFAIK, Javascript doesn't have any concept of variable variables, like how in php you can do `$sections->$test`.