# how to pass value in jquery function to retrieve the data

Tags: jquery, html, json

I want to pass value of x (time)  as an argument in the function so that I can read the relevant data from the JSON.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>JSON Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="placeholder"></div>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  var x="time";

  $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
    var output="<ul>";
    for (var i in data.data) 
       {
        output+="<li>" + data.data[i].x + "</li>";
```

<-- in place of data.data[i].x if use data.data[i].svctime   then i am getting my expected output, but I want to pass value from  variable only!-->

```
     }

    output+="</ul>";
    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
    });
 </script>


 </body>
 </html>
```

Json File (data.Json)

```
{

  "data": [
    {
        "time": "0",
        "count": 19079118,
        "percent": "68.27%"
    },
    {
        "time": "1",
        "count": 7542910,
        "percent": "26.99%"
    },
    {
        "time": "2",
        "count": 877308,
        "percent": "3.14%"
    },
    {
        "time": "3",
        "count": 234513,
        "percent": "0.84%"
    },
    {
        "time": "4",
        "count": 84972,
        "percent": "0.30%"
    }

]
}
```

My expected output (while using data.data[i].time):

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

The Output I am seeing is (while using data.data[i].x):

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

Please suggest me how to pass string to retrieve through function

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get property of object in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695243/get-property-of-object-in-javascript)

Comment: I checked with that, that was not, what I am expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var i in data.data) 
{
output+="<li>" + data.data[i][x] + "</li>";  
}
```

Comment: It would be better to add an explanation along with your code.