# Get value of Json object

Tags: jquery, json

i have a object type of JSon
Ex:

```
[{"RowError":"","RowState":2,"Table":[{"ID":"1","item":"2","cate":"tran","sTITLE":"translation"},{"ID":"2","item":"3","cate":"tran1","sTITLE":"translation1"}]
```

How can i get "Table" in object ? thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get property of object in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695243/get-property-of-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You missed `}]` at the last of your json. Try like following.

```js
var model = [{"RowError":"","RowState":2,"Table":[{"ID":"1","item":"2","cate":"tran","sTITLE":"translation"},{"ID":"2","item":"3","cate":"tran1","sTITLE":"translation1"}]}];
var table = model[0].Table;
console.log(table);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your JSon is not a valid one u missed the braces

```
[
    {
        "RowError": "",
        "RowState": 2,
        "Table": [
            {
                "ID": "1",
                "item": "2",
                "cate": "tran",
                "sTITLE": "translation"
            },
            {
                "ID": "2",
                "item": "3",
                "cate": "tran1",
                "sTITLE": "translation1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

correct JSON

```
var Jsonob = [
    {
        "RowError": "",
        "RowState": 2,
        "Table": [
            {
                "ID": "1",
                "item": "2",
                "cate": "tran",
                "sTITLE": "translation"
            },
            {
                "ID": "2",
                "item": "3",
                "cate": "tran1",
                "sTITLE": "translation1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
console.log(Jsonob[0].Table)
```